# Simulator crashes on AQMEIOManager

Tags: ios, simulator, mpmediaplayercontroller

The simulator crashes when trying to play audio.

```
13:22:14.211 App [2965:5603]  <0xb03e7000> Error '!obj' trying to fetch default input device's sample rate
13:22:14.211 App [2965:5603]  <0xb03e7000> Error getting audio input device sample rate: '!obj'
13:22:14.213 App [2965:5603]  <0xb03e7000> AQMEIOManager::FindIOUnit: error '!dev'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Selecting "internal microphone" instead of "Soundbooth 3.0" in the sound system settings for input did the trick.

Conclusion: The simulator does not seem to like anything other than the internal microphone.

Comment: Same fix here. Changed from my Podcast mic to "Internal Microphone."

Comment: Could also be default sound *output* (eg. was set to Airplay in my case). THanks.

Comment: If you don't have an internal microphone, such as on the new Mac Pro, a workaround to avoid the crashing issue is to check first whether you're running in the simulator (with TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR, say) before triggering a sound.

Comment: I can't believe that I just connected an Apple Headset to my Mac Pro in order to fix my unit tests...... But it works just fine, and I didn't have to change a single line of code.

Comment: Changed from system to headphone and headphone to system not working, it fails every time in simulator with crash.

Answer (score 2):

My mac mini don't have an internal microphone,the Setting->sound->input list is empty.
It worked when I insert an external one .

Answer (score 1):

iDeveloper's answer fixed this crash for me as well, although in my case the sound system setting had its input set to my digidesign card.   The point is, this crash happens when the System Preferences "Sound" setting for input is set to something other than internal mic.