# AVAudioPlayer Error using iOS Simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, runtime-error, avaudioplayer

following problem:

```
<0xb03e7000> Error '!obj' trying to fetch default input device's sample rate
<0xb03e7000> Error getting audio input device sample rate: '!obj'
<0xb03e7000> AQMEIOManager::FindIOUnit: error '!dev'
```

I found this problem already here on stackoverflow but none of the 
provided solutions worked for me.

Code:

```
#import "CJTActionViewController.h"

@interface CJTActionViewController()

@property NSURL *url;
@property NSData *songFile;
@property AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

@end

@implementation CJTActionViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/cannon_01.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    self.songFile = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:self.url];
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:self.songFile error:nil];
    self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    self.audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
}

- (IBAction)firePressed(id):sender
{
    [self.audioPlayer play];
}

@end
```

Delegate is set. Dont know if its important but on another mac this
code runs without problems.

I use ios 6.1 and simulator 6.1

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had this same problem, and was able to fix it by adjusting the sound settings on the mac I am running the simulator on, per [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603743/ios-6-crashes-on-aqmeiomanager). I was using an external sound card, and changing the audio settings on my mac in the following way did the trick:

- Input: Internal Microphone
- Output: Internal Speakers

Hope this helps. My code is very similar to yours, and I don't think this is a problem with your code at all.

Comment: Thank you! Microphone input was empty and osx did not detect any input source. I inserted jack in microphone input and the error disappeared.

Comment: Can confirm, plugging headphones into my input port resolved this issue, how weird!

Comment: I had an iSight camera connected to my mac mini and then this error occurred.  Unplugged the iSight and this error went away.  Thanks for the tip to check audio.

Comment: Changed from system to headphone and headphone to system not working, it fails every time in simulator with crash. in watch app

Answer (score 3):

Confirmed that attaching an audio input device (and restarting the computer) solves the problem. I got this error when shifting from a Macbook Air to a Mac Pro Cylinder after pulling the Git repo over.

I attached my Bose AE bluetooth headset and finally got a meaningful message from Xcode, but it was still aborting:

```
16:04:10.781 WARNING:   246: Default audio device changed. Restart the simulator to have it use the newly-selected device.
2015-04-21 16:04:19.790 FatBirdsPetAdventure[1622:84473] 16:04:19.790 ERROR:     56: Start: Mach message timeout. Apparently deadlocked. Aborting now.
```

After restarting the simulator and doing the XCode dance (delete app from simulator, clean project, rebuild) I got another message:

```
16:06:13.847 ERROR:     56: Initialize: Mach message timeout. Apparently deadlocked. Aborting now.
```

Finally after restarting the machine, there are no more errors.

Answer (score 2):

I spent hours trying to figure this out, if you don't have a microphone or input device then xcode will fail to initialize AVAudioPlayer properly.

That is why plugging in some type of input device works, AVAudioPlayer is searching for an input device . You can run the same app on an iPhone and it will work just fine.

So just plugin some type of input device when running on simulator, I haven't found a way to work around this yet. And it's probably not recommended either.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was:
- Set the System preference, Audio input to something else than Internal Mic
- In Simulator, set the input to Internal Mic
If both of them are the same, it "locks" the Mic somehow.

To all: thanks for answers. I really thought it was my programming bad, but really, it's due to bad design by Apple.
This topic was raised 6 years ago and Apple has still not get rid of this bug!

Comment: Can you provide a link to the bug?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this very same issue, but had speakers connected on the headphones jack. Removed the jack, fiddled with the System preferences output audio back to Built-in speakers, then quit Xcode and simulator and relaunch fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try plugging in a headphone attached with microphone and hopefully the issue'll be solved. Also restart xcode and simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, I tried changing the audio settings but it did not help me, I checked that this issue is happening with the simulators that run lower than 14.0 OS, I ran the code in the simulator with OS 14.4, then it worked for me.