# Xcode: sigABRT in alcMakeContextCurrent

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xcode5, game-center

I was fiddling around trying to get Game Center Leaderboards to work. After becoming frustrated, I just removed the code that I added. However, I now am stuck with this error, even though I deleted it! It almost feels like I ruined a perfectly finished game.

Specifically, here is when the error occurred:
1) I am using cocos2d.
2) I copy and pasted GKAuthentication into my project, then I imported the .h into my first cocos2d scene.
3) I then got the sigABRT error, and decided to remove the import. However, the error persisted.
4) I then removed GKAuthentication files from the project completely. However, the error still persists.

```
+ (bool) makeContextCurrent:(ALCcontext*) context deviceReference:(ALCdevice*) deviceReference
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if(!alcMakeContextCurrent(context)) //sigABRT occurs here
        {
            if(nil != deviceReference)
            {
                CHECK_ALC_CALL(deviceReference);
            }
            else
            {
                OAL_LOG_ERROR(@"Could not make context %p current.  Pass in a device reference for better diagnostic info.", context);
            }
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Strange thing: The simulator causes this error, but on the phone it works great.

It apparently has to do with the audio (?!). I have no idea what GKAuthentication has to do with this. Seems like a sudden error. Here is the error message from the console:

```
cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
cocos2d: GL supports shareable VAO: NO
AudioStreamBasicDescription:  2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved
2014-03-10 15:04:43.058 GaUi[40423:907]  <com.apple.main-thread> Start: Mach message timeout. Apparently deadlocked. Aborting now.
(lldb)
```

Comment: what sound file are you playing there? If it's a sound effect (rather than music) it should be mono (message '2 ch' indicates it is a stereo effect)

Comment: Apparently it's due to an error in the MacBook Air. Sometimes when it resumes from sleep mode, the audio doesn't work, and therefore it causes errors in the simulator. I restarted my computer and it works fine.

Comment: It was an audio problem for me. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318706/avaudioplayer-error-using-ios-simulator

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my Mac Book Pro and Mac Mini, rebooting the computer solves the problem.