# iOS Speech - audioEngine inputNode throws Mach message timeout error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudioengine

I am playing with iOS's speech recognition and added microphone usage request in my `Info.plist`. On recording, the app displays a pop up for requesting access as expected

`MyApp would like to access the microphone`

However, if I wait more than a few seconds to respond, the app crashes with the error message: **RPCTimeout.mm:55:_ReportRPCTimeout: Initialize: Mach message timeout. Apparently deadlocked. Aborting now.**

The code that caused the crash is the line `let node = audioEngine.inputNode`

```
let node = audioEngine.inputNode 

let recordingFormat = node.outputFormat(forBus: 0)

node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { buffer, _ in
    self.request.append(buffer)
}
```

I did some research and the common solution to this error is making sure audio setting on the Mac is set to use Internal Speakers for input and output, which I already have.

If I set a guard on the node like below then XCode throws the error: **Value of type 'AVAudioInputNode' has no member 'inputNode'**

```
guard let node = audioEngine.inputNode.inputNode else {
    return
}
```

Comment: Does it crash on real device or just in simulator ?

Comment: @Mosbah just the simulator

Comment: This just started happening to my code (which worked properly in Xcode 11.5) when I switched to the Xcode 12 beta. I considered filing a radar, but if the problem already existed, I'll hold off on that.

Comment: anybody found any solution?

Comment: i got help from this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18552809/339171